# SQL update multiple rows with multiple values in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've scoured this site and found a few posts but nothing that quite fits the bill for me.

```
company_no  site_no sam_code    cost_code   prev_year_end   period_end_date prev_period_end ledger_type_cnp actual_value    actual_fcv  actual_fav  actual_fcq  actual_faq
G1  51  6   0   2014-02-28 00:00:00.00  2015-02-28 00:00:00.00  2015-01-31 00:00:00.00  NOM 791.94  791.94  NULL    0   NULL
G1  51  6   0   2014-08-31 00:00:00.00  2015-02-28 00:00:00.00  2015-01-31 00:00:00.00  NOM 791.94  791.94  NULL    0   NULL
G1  51  6   GIE 2014-02-28 00:00:00.00  2015-02-28 00:00:00.00  2015-01-31 00:00:00.00  NOM -832.14 -832.14 0   0   0
G1  51  6   GIE 2014-08-31 00:00:00.00  2015-02-28 00:00:00.00  2015-01-31 00:00:00.00  NOM -791.94 -791.94 0   0   0
G1  51  7   0   2014-02-28 00:00:00.00  2015-02-28 00:00:00.00  2015-01-31 00:00:00.00  NOM -1157.32    -1157.32    NULL    0   NULL
G1  51  7   0   2014-08-31 00:00:00.00  2015-02-28 00:00:00.00  2015-01-31 00:00:00.00  NOM -1157.32    -1157.32    NULL    0   NULL
G1  51  7   L01 2014-02-28 00:00:00.00  2015-02-28 00:00:00.00  2015-01-31 00:00:00.00  NOM 1157.32 1157.32 NULL    3570    NULL
G1  51  7   L01 2014-08-31 00:00:00.00  2015-02-28 00:00:00.00  2015-01-31 00:00:00.00  NOM 1157.32 1157.32 NULL    3570    NULL
```

Apologies for the table above, I tried to attach an image but didn't have the reputation points to do so.

My issue is that I have a duplication in table dnl.  The rows are identical except for columns prev_year_end and the actual_* columns.  What I am looking to do is first of all set all the prev_year_end actual_* values for '2014-08-31 00:00:00.000' to match the actual_* values for prev_year_end '2014-02-28 00:00:00.000.  (I hope that made sense)

So far I've tried the update with:

```
    update dnl
set actual_value =
    (select actual_value
    from dnl where (period_end_date <= '2015-02-28 00:00:00.000'
    and period_end_date >= '2014-09-30 00:00:00.000')
    and prev_year_end = '2014-02-28 00:00:00.000'
    and company_no = 'G1')
where 
    (period_end_date <= '2015-02-28 00:00:00.000'
    and period_end_date >= '2014-09-30 00:00:00.000')
and prev_year_end = '2014-08-31 00:00:00.000'
and company_no = 'G1'
```

and with:

```
update a
set a.actual_value =
    (select b.actual_value
    from dnl b where (b.period_end_date <= '2015-02-28 00:00:00.000'
    and b.period_end_date >= '2014-09-30 00:00:00.000')
    and b.prev_year_end = '2014-02-28 00:00:00.000'
    and b.company_no = 'G1')
FROM dnl a
INNER JOIN dnl b
        ON a.period_end_date = b.period_end_date
where 
    (a.period_end_date <= '2015-02-28 00:00:00.000'
    and a.period_end_date >= '2014-09-30 00:00:00.000')
and a.prev_year_end = '2014-08-31 00:00:00.000'
and a.company_no = 'G1'
```

But each fail with a message:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

From this point I'm a bit stuck and was wondering if anyone would be a life saver and offer any advice please?

Comment: Look at the result of the subquery `select .actual_value...`. Does it really return more than one row? If it does, fix that.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the response.
It does return more than 1 result.  My issue is that the duplication has occurred to over 7000 rows, so to amend each row individually isn't viable.  I'm trying to overlay the results for prev_year_end 2014-02-28 on top of 2014-08-31 as everything else is the same so that ultimately all of the rows with a prev_year_end of 2014-02-28 can be removed

Comment: You miss the point. If you return multiple rows, which one of them should the dbms use to update "actual_value"? Use a join, or include more columns in the subquery's WHERE clause (probably company_no, site_no, sam_code, and cost_code).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do an inner join into a temp table, followed by a delete of any of the rows you wish to replace. Finish it by inserting back your values from the temp table.

```
SELECT A.column1, A.column2, B.column3 as AcolumnName 
INTO #Temptbl
FROM tbl A 
JOIN tbl B ON XXXX
```

Replace XX on your join condition, I'm not too sure on what you're joining with based on your description I would say there's a date involved.  Then add the delete to the cells you want to replace followed by a reinsert..

```
DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE datecondition

INSERT INTO tbl (SELECT * FROM #Temptbl)
```

If you're worried about your delete.  I would follow up step one w/a Select * FROM #Temptbl to see the results before deleting.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the easiest syntax to read. Note that each subquery returns a single value.

```
update dnl
set actual_value = (select actual_value from dnl d where d.company_no = dnl.company_no and d.site_no = dnl.site_no and d.sam_code = dnl.sam_code and d.cost_code = dnl.cost_code and d.prev_year_end = '2014-02-28 00:00:00.000'),
    actual_fcv =   (select actual_fcv   from dnl d where d.company_no = dnl.company_no and d.site_no = dnl.site_no and d.sam_code = dnl.sam_code and d.cost_code = dnl.cost_code and d.prev_year_end = '2014-02-28 00:00:00.000'),
    actual_fav =   (select actual_fav   from dnl d where d.company_no = dnl.company_no and d.site_no = dnl.site_no and d.sam_code = dnl.sam_code and d.cost_code = dnl.cost_code and d.prev_year_end = '2014-02-28 00:00:00.000'),
    actual_fcq =   (select actual_fcq   from dnl d where d.company_no = dnl.company_no and d.site_no = dnl.site_no and d.sam_code = dnl.sam_code and d.cost_code = dnl.cost_code and d.prev_year_end = '2014-02-28 00:00:00.000'),
    actual_faq =   (select actual_faq   from dnl d where d.company_no = dnl.company_no and d.site_no = dnl.site_no and d.sam_code = dnl.sam_code and d.cost_code = dnl.cost_code and d.prev_year_end = '2014-02-28 00:00:00.000')
where prev_year_end = '2014-08-31 00:00:00.000';
```

---

You'll get more replies when you include CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements.

```
create table dnl (
  company_no char(2),
  site_no integer,
  sam_code integer,
  cost_code varchar(5),
  prev_year_end  timestamp, 
  period_end_date timestamp,
  prev_period_end timestamp,
  ledger_type_cnp char(3),
  actual_value float,
  actual_fcv  float,
  actual_fav  float,
  actual_fcq  float,
  actual_faq float
);

insert into dnl values 
('G1',  51, 6,  '0',   '2014-02-28 00:00:00.00',  '2015-02-28 00:00:00.00',  '2015-01-31 00:00:00.00', 'NOM',   791.94,   791.94,  NULL,    0,   NULL),
('G1',  51, 6,  '0',   '2014-08-31 00:00:00.00',  '2015-02-28 00:00:00.00',  '2015-01-31 00:00:00.00', 'NOM',   791.94,   791.94,  NULL,    0,   NULL),
('G1',  51, 6,  'GIE', '2014-02-28 00:00:00.00',  '2015-02-28 00:00:00.00',  '2015-01-31 00:00:00.00', 'NOM',  -832.14,  -832.14,     0,    0,   0),
('G1',  51, 6,  'GIE', '2014-08-31 00:00:00.00',  '2015-02-28 00:00:00.00',  '2015-01-31 00:00:00.00', 'NOM',  -791.94,  -791.94,     0,    0,   0),
('G1',  51, 7,  '0',   '2014-02-28 00:00:00.00',  '2015-02-28 00:00:00.00',  '2015-01-31 00:00:00.00', 'NOM', -1157.32, -1157.32,  NULL,    0,   NULL),
('G1',  51, 7,  '0',   '2014-08-31 00:00:00.00',  '2015-02-28 00:00:00.00',  '2015-01-31 00:00:00.00', 'NOM', -1157.32, -1157.32,  NULL,    0,   NULL),
('G1',  51, 7,  'L01', '2014-02-28 00:00:00.00',  '2015-02-28 00:00:00.00',  '2015-01-31 00:00:00.00', 'NOM',  1157.32,  1157.32,  NULL, 3570,   NULL),
('G1',  51, 7,  'L01', '2014-08-31 00:00:00.00',  '2015-02-28 00:00:00.00',  '2015-01-31 00:00:00.00', 'NOM',  1157.32,  1157.32,  NULL, 3570,   NULL);
```